# Excel export 1:n

Tags: excel, pivot-table, epplus

I've got a database with a 1:n relation. For example a Shop got about 3000 products. I've exported a table with all shops. Of course I could something like this:

```
Shop0;SomeShopInformation;SomeShopInformation;...;ProductA
Shop0;SomeShopInformation;SomeShopInformation;...;ProductB
Shop0;SomeShopInformation;SomeShopInformation;...;ProductC
```

But I really don't like that. I would like to create table with products and a table with shops. The product table would reference the shop table. But what is the best way to do that in excel. 
If thought about 2 possible solutions:

Solution A) Would be give every shop an ID. In a product table, I would just reference that ID(quite the same like my database does it). The problem is, that it would be quite difficult to create diagrams etc. because the user should be able to create statistics,... quite easy(with the exported data).

Solution B) Would be to use something like pivot tables. The main problem here is that I don't get it how I just can create a simple sub table. Like:

```
+Shop0;SomeShopInformation;SomeShopInformation;...;
  ProductA;SomeProductInformation
  ProductB;SomeProductInformation
  ProductC;SomeProductInformation
```

How can I use multiple columns in a pivot table. Or how can I create some sort of sub table like some datagrid controls can do it?

Oh and btw. It should work with EPPlus library.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about EPPlus but in Excel there is a choice of PivotTable layouts, for example with data as at the top of the image (similar to your example):

[image: SO19447059 example]